# Calling setState() in a function, and proceeding to the next sibling function after state has changed- is it possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, state

let say I've got something like this:

In context provider:

```
toggleLogin(isLoggedIn) {
     this.setState({
         isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn
     });
}
```

In login component using context:

```
(....)
this.props.context.toggleLogin(true);
this.props.history.push("/"); 
(....)
```

I want this.props.history.push("/") or any else function I'll put after toggleLogin() execute only when toggleLogin function finishes updating state. Right now it's working good.

But I think because setState is async, under the hood it works like:

1. execute toggleLogin
2. start executing setState in toggleLogin
3. execute this.props.history.push("/")
4. finish setState in toggleLogin

And it's working in my case because state is set really fast.

But because its working it seems that's it's working this way:

1. execute toggleLogin
2. execute setState
3. execute this.props.history.push("/")

I'm checking isLoggedIn state in "/" route component so thats why I want it to execute only after setState is finished. This is another component so I can't use setState callback.

Is `this.props.history.push("/")` really executed after toggleLogin is finished? If not, how can I make it do this? 
I don't find making toggleLogin `async` and awaiting `setState` and then using `then()` in login component a good idea - maybe I'm wrong, I'm just starting in ReactJS.

Can anyone enlighten me with right path of doing this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous and there is no guarantee that's gonna be finished when you call `history.push`. To make sure all updates are done before executing something use the second argument of `setState` which allow us to pass a `callback` to execute after the state's update. You could pass this callback to `toggleLogin`

```
this.props.context.toggleLogin(true, () => this.props.history.push('/'))
```

And in `toggleLogin`

```
toggleLogin(isLoggedIn, cb) {
     this.setState({
         isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn
     },  cb);
}
```

Comment: I've thought about it already and I can't do this this way-  I have to call this.props.history.push() in my login component- context provider doesnt even know that router exists as it's wrapped around whole App, and Router is used just deeper in the app.

Comment: Wow, I didnt think about this lovely anonymous arrow function with its lovely "this" binding :D Thank you!